# create n variables java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is it possible to create n variables within a loop. Something like

```
for(int x = 0; int x <  noOfThreads){
        //create new threads here
    }
```

I need to create the number of threads specified as an runtime argument. Not too sure how to go about this.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to have variables for that? Isn't it enough to just create N thread instances?

Comment: as in: new threadClass() ? this seems to show an error?

Comment: Your target problem doesn't seem so clear for me. Please, describe what is your task and what you expect as result. There many ways how to work with java threads. For example you can pay attention on java ExecutorService. It's part of modern api for working with threads.<br/> final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

Comment: What the héll is "threadClass"?  Why not just `new Thread(...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create and start the threads in the loop.

If you need to keep references to the `Thread` objects, then put them in a collection such as `ArrayList`:

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for(int x = 0; x <  noOfThreads; x++){
    Thread t = new Thread(/* ... */);
    threads.add(t);
    // do something with t
}
```

Comment: @Sarconi All right, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

In C# I would do something like this:

```
List<Object> L = new List<Object>();

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    L.Add(new Object());
```